# filtering a pytables table on pandas import

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I have a dataset created with pytables that I am trying to import into a pandas dataframe.  I can't apply a `where` filter to the `read_hdf` step.  I'm on pandas '0.12.0'

My sample pytables data:

```
import tables
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class BranchFlow(tables.IsDescription):
    branch = tables.StringCol(itemsize=25, dflt=' ')
    flow = tables.Float32Col(dflt=0)

filters = tables.Filters(complevel=8)
h5 = tables.openFile('foo.h5', 'w')
tbl = h5.createTable('/', 'BranchFlows', BranchFlow, 
            'Branch Flows', filters=filters, expectedrows=50e6) 

for i in range(25):
    element = tbl.row
    element['branch'] = str(i)
    element['flow'] = np.random.randn()
    element.append()
tbl.flush()
h5.close()
```

Which I can import just fine into a dataframe:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('foo.h5')
print store
print pd.read_hdf('foo.h5', 'BranchFlows').head()
```

which shows:

```
In [10]: print store
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: foo.h5
/BranchFlows            frame_table [0.0.0] (typ->generic,nrows->25,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[branch,flow])

In [11]: print pd.read_hdf('foo.h5', 'BranchFlows').head()
  branch      flow
0      0 -0.928300
1      1 -0.256454
2      2 -0.945901
3      3  1.090994
4      4  0.350750
```

But I can't get the filter to work on the flow column:

```
pd.read_hdf('foo.h5', 'BranchFlows', where=['flow>0.5'])

<snip traceback>

TypeError: passing a filterable condition to a non-table indexer [field->flow,op->>,value->[0.5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from a PyTables directly created table only allows you to directly read the (entire) table. You must write it using pandas tools (in Table format) in order to use the pandas selection mechanism (because the meta data that pandas needs is not present - it could be done, but would take some work).

So, read your table in like above, then create a new one, and indicate table format. See [here for docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables)

```
In [6]: df.to_hdf('foo.h5','BranchFlowsTable',data_columns=True,table=True)

In [24]: with pd.get_store('foo.h5') as store:
    print(store)
   ....:     
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: foo.h5
/BranchFlows                 frame_table [0.0.0] (typ->generic,nrows->25,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[branch,flow])
/BranchFlowsTable            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->25,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[branch,flow])    

In [7]: pd.read_hdf('foo.h5','BranchFlowsTable',where='flow>0.5')
Out[7]: 

   branch      flow
14     14  1.503739
15     15  0.660297
17     17  0.685152
18     18  1.156073
20     20  0.994792
21     21  1.266463
23     23  0.927678
```

Comment: I can't remember why I didn't just create a pandas dataframe to start out with.  Right now, numpy throws a ``ValueError: array is too big.`` when I try to read the real dataset in, but that's another issue.

Comment: you can do this in parts (pass ``append=True``) and you can pass partial frames and build up your table, see [here for more](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore)